# Prove uniform convergence of $\sum (-1)^{n}\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ for all bounded interval and discuss absolute convergence of the series of functions

Tags: analysis

I'm struggling on proving the uniform convergence on all intervals, since I have already seen that it is not absolutely convergent for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

Let's see it is not absolutely convergent.

> We have to study the convergence of $\sum |(-1)^{n}\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}|=\sum \frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\geq \sum \frac{n}{n^2}=\sum \frac{1}{n}=\infty$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

Let's try to prove uniform convergence for all bounded intervals.

> First of all, as the question asks for bounded intervals and not compact sets should it be an error to study uniform convergence on $[a,b]$ with $a<b$? Or should I study it on $(a,b)$ which I assume it is a more general result? Anyways, I tried applying [Dirichlet for series of functions](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence), since I already know that [Weierstarss M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) won't work (Weierstrass M-test also proves the absolute convergence of the series of functions which I have already proved it doesn't). Defining $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$ and $g_n(x)=\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ we get
>
> $(1)$ $sup_{x\in [a,b]}|\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n|=sup_{x\in [a,b]}|-1+1-1+...+(-1)^N|=0$, $\forall N$
>
> $(2)$ $g_n(x)=\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ is monotone. If $[a,b]\subsetneq(-\infty,0]$ then is decreasing, and if $[a,b]\subsetneq [0,\infty)$ it is increasing. Also, it is uniformly convergent to $0$.
> $$sup_{x\in[a,b]}\Big|\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\Big|=\frac{b^2+n}{n^2}\longrightarrow0$$ if $[a,b]\subset[0,\infty)$ and $$sup_{x\in[a,b]}\Big|\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}\Big|=\frac{a^2+n}{n^2}\longrightarrow0$$ if $[a,b]\subset(-\infty,0]$.
>
> Hence, $\sum (-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent for bounded intervals not containing zero, so $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}^{*}$

But, what I have proved is that the series of functions is uniformly convergent on all compacts not containing zero and not on $\mathbb{R}$ which was the claim of the exercise. Have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are making things too complicated.

$\sum(-1)^{n}\frac {x^{2}+n} {n^{2}}$ is the sum of the series $\sum(-1)^{n}\frac {x^{2}} {n^{2}}$ and the convergent series $\sum(-1)^{n}\frac 1  n$ (of constants).  So uniform convergence of the sum is equivalent to uniform convergence of $x^{2}\sum(-1)^{n}\frac 1  {n^{2}}$. As long as $x^{2}$ remains bounded this series is uniformly convergent.